# button click event inside popup in WPF any idea?

Tags: wpf, events, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

am trying to achieve the functionality of Outlook style of Datepicker control.

I have a textbox which am applying a style which looks exactly same as in Outlook but my problem is popup having a calendar and two button as Today and none.As soon as click on Today button the textbox value should set to todays date and if i click None the text box value has to set as none.

The style i have used is

```
         <Style x:Key="tbCalendarStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                    </Border>
                    <ToggleButton Template="{StaticResource IconButton}"
                          MaxHeight="21" 
                          Margin="-1,0,0,0" 
                          Name="PopUpImageButton" 
                          Focusable="False"
                          IsChecked="False">
                        <ToggleButton.Content>
                            <Path x:Name="btnArrow4" Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="10" Fill="Black" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z "/>
                        </ToggleButton.Content>                        


                    </ToggleButton>
                    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=PopUpImageButton, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="CustomPopup" Margin="0,-1,0,0" PopupAnimation="Fade" StaysOpen="False">

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" removed="BlueViolet">
                            <Grid >
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="164"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Calendar Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,-1,0,0" x:Name="CalDisplay"
                                  SelectedDate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource calendarConverter}}" 
                                  Focusable="False" 
                                  DisplayDate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Text, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource calendarConverter}}"    
                                  >
                                    <Control.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Calendar.SelectedDatesChanged">
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PopUpImageButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked">
                                                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="False"></DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame>
                                                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                    </Control.Triggers>
                                </Calendar>
                            </Grid>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                                <Button Content="Today" Grid.Row="1" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20 0 0 10" Name="btnToday">
                                    <Button.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                                            // what should i do to achieve the above logic
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                    </Button.Triggers>
                                </Button>

                                <Button Content="None" Grid.Row="1" Margin="30 0 0 10" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="btnNone">
                                    <Button.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">

                                        </EventTrigger>
                                    </Button.Triggers>
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PopUpImageButton" Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PopUpImageButton" Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Any help or idea to achieve this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you in Generic.xaml or Window.Resources?

Comment: Ahh ok I get you. Take a look at what I posted you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a custom control then I suggest you to override the method OnApplyTemplate and use GetTemplatedChild to find the Button, subscribe to its click and thats it except you will have to find the TextBox and set its Text inside the handler.

If you cannot do so for whatever reason here is a small trick how to make it still work

Take a look at this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    x:Class="WPFControls.Generic"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFControls">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyChildControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyChildControl}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox x:Name="tbx1"/>
                        <Button Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Click="OnClick"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
....
```

And this is the code behind for Generic.xaml dictionary.

```
public partial class Generic
{
    public void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyChildControl control = FindAncestor<MyChildControl>((DependencyObject)sender);
        TextBox tbx = control.Template.FindName("tbx1", control) as TextBox;
        tbx.Text = "It works!";
    }

    public static T FindAncestor<T>(DependencyObject current) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);

        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current is T)
            {
                return (T)current;
            }

            current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
        };

        return null;
    }
}
```

This is mine MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window ....>
    <Grid>
        <local:MyChildControl Content="Click me!"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I could get your idea...please explain me

Comment: Have you copied the code and tried it out? Is it working? It should have. :) The idea is to have code behind for resources and to define click hander.

Comment: I get this error even after adding x:class in ResourceDictionary 'ResourceDictionary' root element requires a x:Class attribute to support event handlers in the XAML file. Either remove the event handler for the Click event, or add a x:Class attribute to

Comment: This means you havent done exactly so like I showed you. Dont forget to set x:Class in the definition of your ResourceDictionary in XAML.

Comment: Now i got what your are trying to explain me...thanks let me try and will let you know the result..

Comment: Thanks i have created as per you said.:)

Answer (score 0):

The general way to attach event handlers to elements that are defined within a `ControlTemplate` is to override the [`FrameworkElement.OnApplyTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    Button button = (Button)Template.FindName("btnToday", this);
    button.Click += SomeClickHandler;
}
```

UPDATE >>>

Where I have used `this` (as the second input parameter) above, it stands for the `templatedParent` input parameter. The correct value will depend on which object the `Template` was applied to... in this case, I believe that it should be the `this` object.

UPDATE 2 >>>

Sorry, I thought that you could write a `Click` event handler. Here is one:

```
private void SomeClickHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Set your DateTime here
}
```

Comment: i have added the above method in .cs file of xaml where i set my actual textbox but i am getting error:No overload for method 'FindName' takes 1 arguments

Comment: Ah sorry, my memory's not great. I forgot the `templatedParent` input parameter... I've updated the example now.

Comment: Thanks but why i get event handler name doesn't exist,even i use OnClick as Event name.

Comment: In my example, `SomeClickHandler` is the name of a `Click` event handler that *you* have to implement... I just made up that name as an example. I've updated my code example with a handler.